# Pull message in Google cloud pub/sub getting blank message body

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I published a message in a topic and then in the google cloud, clicked on subscriptions,
clicked on one of the subscriptions, and then clicked on the pull. I did see a message there
But it was blank, and also under the ACK column, the entry was - `Deadline exceeded.`
what could be the reason for this? Is there a time before I have to pull
the messages; otherwise, they will be lost?

[image]

Comment: I'm going to guess that the deadline exceeded message is related to the usage of the console.  Imagine YOU sitting at the console and you pull a message.  The message is now pending acknowledgement.  Either ACK, NACK or timeout.  I believe that you have some finite period at the console to ACK the message before it automatically times out at which point it is nacked.   For the empty body ... I'd suggest trying the gcloud subscriptions pull command for testing ... https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/pull

Comment: Hi @dnaiel , did the above comment resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kolban is correct about what the "Deadline exceeded" under the "Ack" column means. When you first pulled the message, an "ACK" button should have appeared under the "Ack" column, which you can click to acknowledge the message. However, after the message's acknowledgement deadline has passed, the "ACK" button is replaced with the "Deadline exceeded" message, indicating that it is too late to acknowledge the message. The message then becomes eligible for redelivery; it is not lost, but you will need to pull it again in order to acknowledge it.

The blank message body is likely due to your message body encompassing multiple lines (the first line being blank). Only the first line is shown by default. You can view the entirety of your message body by clicking the dropdown arrow on the right-hand side of the row (i.e. the dropdown arrow next to the "Deadline exceeded" message in your screenshot).